# Are these Zener diodes bad?

Tags: diodes, zener, failure-analysis

I am diode testing Zener diodes and getting conduction in both directions. Does this mean that the diodes are bad or is the diode test just allowing the breakdown voltage to be reached thus causing conduction?

Comment: What is the zener voltage supposed to be? Most meters apply less than 5V to the DUT.

Comment: Zeners usually have about 1 V forward voltage drop at a few mA (I've in the non zener mode) and the zener voltage in the reverse biased direction at rated test current.

Comment: it depends on how you test. With a diode tester from the multimeter (e.g. Fluke 177), a Zener diode has the same properties as a silicon diode. That means: 600 to 700 mV drop in one direction and everything that the diode tester outputs (overflow) in the other, because the diode has a high resistance.

Comment: In my experience, the most common failure mode for zeners is that they short-circuit.  If you're testing using a multimeter and it's conducting both ways then it's bad.

Comment: What are the Zener diode part numbers, how are you testing them, and how much 'conduction' are you getting in each direction?

Comment: they usually need several ma of current to "regulate" properly.

Comment: @BruceAbbott in some, I am getting 0.8V forward biased and 1.5V reversed. Also I am not seeing part numbers on them. These are the small orange and black ones.

Comment: If you don't know the part number, how do you even know they are zeners? (I bet they are, but...). Where did you get them from?  I guess you tested them with a digital multimeter on 'diode test', right? If so, which brand and model is your meter?